# IOBluetooth Mouse Battery Level

Tags: swift, macos, bluetooth, iobluetooth

Is it possible to read battery levels from a Bluetooth mouse (Magic Mouse 2 in this case), using the [IOBluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iobluetooth) framework?

Would this require writing a request as data through a L2CAP or RFCOMM channel?

I got as far as reading the SDP service records, but am not sure how to proceed.